# addEventListener with same handler function to multiple elements

Tags: javascript, this, addeventlistener

My handler function:

```
function move(currentElement){
    //currentElement is the element calling the function.
    //code;
}
```

My addEvent code:

```
var labels = document.getElementsByTagName('label');
for(i = 0; i < labels.length; i++)
    labels[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        move(this);
    });
```

I have multiple labels that I want to assign the handler function to. My way is not working :/

Comment: All though somewhat akward as you could do just `labels[i].addEventListener('click', move)` and use `this` in the function, your version should work just fine

Comment: It works https://jsfiddle.net/e85empsb/

Comment: The fiddle you provided did work.. but when I copy paste the same exact js code in my code.. somehow it does not work.. wow pretty strange. :/